# Physics bullet with drag in Python immediately goes below zero

Tags: python, physics

I am coding a program to find how far a bullet shoots at a 20 degree angle with various parameters with and without drag. For some reason my program immediately calculates the y value of the bullet as being below zero and I think it may be a problem with the physics equations I have used. I don't have the strongest background in physics so after trying my best to figure out where I went wrong I figured I would ask for help. In the graph below I am attempting to display the different distances associated with different timesteps.

```
    import math
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    rho = 1.2754
    Af = math.pi*(16*0.0254)**2/4
    g = -9.8 #m/s^2
    V = 250.0 #m/s
    #equation of motion
    def update(r,V,a,dt):
        return r+V*dt +.5*a*dt*dt, V + a*dt
    #drag force from velocity vector return x and y 
    def drag(Vx,Vy):
        Vmag = math.sqrt(Vx**2+Vy**2)
        Ff = .5*Cd*rho*Af*Vmag**2
        return -Ff * Vx/Vmag, -Ff *Vy/Vmag

    def getTrajectory(dt, th):
        #initialize problem [time,x,y,Vx,Vy]
        state = [[0.0,0.0,0.0, V*math.cos(th), V*math.sin(th)]]

        while state[-1][2] >= 0 : # while y > 0 
            time = state[-1][0] + dt
            Fd = drag(state[-1][3],state[-1][4]) # Vx,Vy
            ax = Fd[0]/m # new x acceleration
            ay = (Fd[1]/m) +g # new y acceleration

            nextX, nextVx = update(state[-1][1], state[-1][3],ax,dt)                                         #x,Vx,acceleration x, dt
            nextY, nextVy = update(state[-1][2], state[-1][4],ay,dt) #y,Vy, acceleration y, dt
            state.append([time,nextX,nextY,nextVx,nextVy])
            # linear interpolation 
            dtf = -state[-1][2]*(state[-2][0]-state[-1][0])/(state[-2][2]-state[-1][2])

            xf,vxf = update(state[-1][1],state[-1][3], ax, dtf)
            print(xf,vxf)
            yf,vyf = update(state[-1][2],state[-1][4], ay, dtf)
            print(yf,vyf)
            state[-1] = [time+dtf,xf,yf,vxf,vyf]
            return state

    delt = 0.01 #timestep
    th = 20.0 * math.pi/180.0 #changing to radians
    m = 2400 #kg

    Cd = 1.0
    tsteps = [0.001,0.01,0.1,1.0,3.0] # trying different timesteps to find the optimal one
    xdistance = [getTrajectory(tstep,th)[-1][1] for tstep in tsteps]
    plt.plot(tsteps,xdistance)
    plt.show()
```

A print of the state variable which contains all of the values of time,x,y,Vx, and Vy after one timestep yields: 
        [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 234.9231551964771, 85.50503583141717]
       ,[0.0, 0.0, -9.540979117872439e-18, 234.9231551964771, 85.50503583141717]]
The first array is the initial conditions with the Vx and Vy broken up into their vectors calculated by the 20 degree angle. The second array should have the bullet flying off with a positive x and y but for some reason the y value is calculated to be -9.54e-18 which quits the getTrajectory method as it is only supposed to continue while y > 0

In order to simplify my problem, I think it may help to look specifically at my update function.

```
    def update(initial,V,a,dt): #current x or y, Velocity in the x or y         direction, acceleration in x or y, timestep
        return initial+V*dt +.5*a*dt*dt, V + a*dt
```

This function is supposed to return an updated x,Vx or an updated y,Vy depending on what is passed. I think this may be where the problem is in the physics equations but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Could you simplify your code a bit? What you have isn't excessively long, but the simpler you can get it (while [still showing the problem you're trying to solve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), of course), the easier it will be for someone to help you and the more likely you are to get that help. In your case, you could probably delete (or comment out) the plotting code, and maybe just limit it to one time step if that makes the code simpler. A short printed output would be enough to demonstrate the problem, if you explain why it doesn't match what you expect.

Comment: @DavidZ i added a few more things to try and explain whats really going on here. Let me know if I should further simplify things.

Comment: The edit definitely helps. Don't get me wrong, your question is fine as is, but I do think simplifying the sample program you provided would help even more. (But thank you for giving a program that's complete enough to run!) I'll take a look at this when I get some time later tonight.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what's going on: in your while loop, you first make a forward time step to compute the kinematic variables at, say, `t = 0.001` from their values at `t = 0`, and then you set `dtf` to a negative value and make a backward time step to compute new values at `t = 0` from the values you just computed at `t = 0.001` (or whatever). I'm not sure why you do that, but at any rate your `update()` function is using the [Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) which is numerically unstable - as you take more and more steps, it often diverges more and more from the true solution in somewhat unpredictable ways. In this case, that turns up as a negative y position, instead of setting it back to 0 as you might expect.

No method of numerical integration is going to give you perfect results, so you can always expect a little bit of inaccuracy, which may be positive or negative. Just because something is a little bit negative isn't *necessarily* cause for concern. (But it could be, depending on the situation.) That being said, you can get better results by using a more robust method of integration, like Runge-Kutta 4th-order (a.k.a. RK4) or a symplectic integrator. But those are somewhat advanced techniques, so I wouldn't worry about them too much for now.

As for the problem at hand, I wonder if you might have a sign error somewhere in your equations, possibly in the line that sets `dtf`. I can't say for sure, though, because I really don't understand how `getTrajectory()` is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an indentation error. The part of determining the location of the zero crossing of `y` starting with the linear interpolation is surely not meant to be part of the integration loop, especially not the `return` statement. Repairing this indentation level gives the output

```
(3745.3646817336303, 205.84399509886356)
(6.278677479133594e-07, -81.7511764639779)

(3745.2091465034314, 205.8432621147464)
(8.637877372419503e-05, -81.75094436152747)

(3743.6311931495325, 205.83605594288176)
(0.01056407140434586, -81.74756057157798)

(3727.977248738945, 205.75827166721402)
(0.1316764390634169, -81.72155620161116)

(3669.3437231150106, 205.73704583954634)
(10.273469073526238, -80.52193274789204)
```